# How to prevent script termination or timeouts?

Tags: php, mysql

I've a simple table containing different actions which should executed at a certain time:

```
ID  |  action | timestamp  | done
================================
 1  |  act_1  | 1415217793 | 0
 2  |  act_2  | 1415217793 | 0
 3  |  act_3  | 1415217793 | 0
 4  |  act_4  | 1415217793 | 0
 5  |  act_5  | 1415217793 | 0
```

When a certain timestamp has been reached the `act_#` gets executed

After `act_#` has been successful executed the `done` column gets the timestamp of execution (to know which has been progressed)

I currently get the data via SQL and running a PHP script with a foreach loop like this (simplified):

```
foreach ( actions as action ){

   // do the action
   $success = do(action);

   if($success){
      //update table and set `done` to a timestamp
   }else{
      //don't update
   }
}
```

The `action` can be pretty resource heavy so it may fail. What if the `action` get's executed but doesn't return `true` or the script stops it's execution for whatever reason?

The `done` column didn't get updated and it will get executed again in the next run.

Is this approach questionable in general? What is "best practice" for this?

Comment: you'd have to update your code to expect (or at least handle) such exceptions. e.g. instead of doing a bulk update to change yuour records to "done" at the end of the script, change each record's status as you process it. that way you'd lost at most one record's partial processing if the script does barf for whatever reason.

Comment: the `do()` method already has `try...catch` and returns false if it throws an error. The status will get update right after the execution (`if($success){...`)

Comment: *what* kind of resource heavy operations are you performing? (database, filesystem, remote servers?) - depending on that the answer is quite different.

Comment: mostly `preg_match`, `DomDocument` operations, mail delivery (PHPMailer) but could grow. It works pretty fine right now but just like to make sure it doesn't get executed twice.